# Can I say I'll have "a tea"?

Tags: pronouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I know it's perfectly grammatical for native speakers to say "I'll have **a** latte/ **a** beer / **a** coke" etc. But is "tea", typically served in a cup, also countable?

Comment: Sure.  I'll have a tea, two coffees, and a Coke.

Comment: @Jim before you begin to eat?

Comment: @Kris - The tea before.  The Coke during. One coffee to finish and one to go....   ;-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Tea originated in Southwest China, where it was used as a medicinal
>   drink." 
>   uncountable
>
> "I drank 5 teas today."
>   countable

[List of countable and uncountable uses of tea](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tea)

Comment: The question is about the drink "typically served in a cup".